# Keep values in charts which update each second

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

In highcharts, we can use the chart which update dynamically : https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

I've got a play button to launch the update of the chart but I was wondering if it is possible to keep the data from the beginning.
I would like a live graph where you can see the data from the moment we launch it and the new ones each second.

Is there an option to set to have this ?

Comment: setInterval is what u need

Comment: are you getting the data from the db

Comment: @sachilaranawaka Yes. The data come from a db through an api

Comment: i think its better id you use something like socket io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        ....,
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    x = yourMethodTofetchNewX()
                    y = yourMethodTofetchNewY()
                    //or fetch them together somehow, depends on your system
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000); // number of miliseconds for the next fetch
            }
        }
    },....
```

You should define a load event where you trigger a function which fetches new data. Then create "*setInterval*" which will call your "*fetch*" function in regular time intervals.

[Here is an example with random data](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/)

Comment: May be I didn't express well what i want, sorry. In your case the oldest values disappear, which I dont want to.

Comment: Ohh I see. Maybe you are looking for _highStock_. Take a look at this example (http://jsfiddle.net/tsaykkrw/)

Comment: Exactly ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just in addition, another example of a live chart where old series points are not removed http://jsfiddle.net/2mnfug5s/